# If charger = unplugged, alert me. Command line script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I want to make a some kind of alert to let me know when the charger has disconnected (the cable doesn't fit into the socket well).

I have this to detect the status of the charger:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online
```

it returns 1 when charging and 0 when on battery.

and this to request a pop-up window:

```
zenity --info --text="Charger unplugged!"
```

I figured some kind of if statement would do the job, having to run it infinitely every second or so.

Then I remembered my days of Arduino where you could program an interrupt, that could trigger the script to run, rather than having to run it all the time.

Not sure what the best way to achieve this is. Does anybody know?

Many thanks.

Comment: [This post](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/remind-unplug-charging-laptop-arch-linux/) uses a simple loop to check battery level. You can store the previous charging state and notify once it changes to unplugged. Just remember to add some delay to avoid excessive CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service, or you can do it in a more simple and primitive way: create a script that will create a fork, redirect it's own `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` and execute an infinite loop that will be constantly checking your `/sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online` file. When the value is `0` it will redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` to the original, in order to show the prompt. To make this an autonomous script, you would have to execute it with crontab `@reboot`.

I think that in the CLI it should work, but I don't know if it would work in a Graphical Desktop Interface

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistance! The command `zenity --info --text="Charger unplugged!"` takes care of creating a graphical alert window, so not sure if i need to use the method of redirecting stderr like you said.

Would you know how to pop those two aforementioned commands into an if statement? Then I'll look into crontab for scheduled execution. I tried turning it into an if command and just got a ton of problems.

Comment: You want to create a script in shell script ?